# What was the short story about a boy who likes to play in the woods by his house and tells his parents he wants to be a tree when he grows up?

Tags: story-identification

What was the short story about a boy who likes to play in the woods by his house and tells his parents he wants to be a tree when he grows up? The story ends with him deciding he won't tell his parents about the bark forming on his skin. A great--and different--example of nature inspiring writing...

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93653/book-identification-about-kid-turning-into-plant ?

Comment: and/or the same as http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/112599/59028 ?

Answer (score 2):

Might this be "[Remember Me](http://www.iblist.com/book19057.htm)" by Nancy Farmer?  I found it in [Firebirds Anthology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebirds_(anthology)), it was copyrighted two years prior, in 2003.

The narrator is a young boy, it is his sister who is strongly drawn to nature and who eventually turns into a tree.  There is some lovely imagery (especially closer to the end) about being close to nature, and being true to one's nature - but there's also a lot about not fitting in to the human world, the reasons she prefers to become a tree instead of growing up human.

It's not a perfect fit, the emphasis on the transformation is a girl who doesn't fit the human world, more than loves the natural world (perhaps because it is from her brother's perspective, and not her viewpoint).  The facts are close enough, though, that I thought I'd suggest it anyway.  I hope you find it.