# Fantasy book cover with tree trunk and boy with skin like tree bark

Tags: story-identification, books, cover-art

My fiance says she read a fantasy book in seventh grade, but can't remember the author or much of the story line. She says the book cover was of a tree trunk in slight shadow and also a boy with skin like tree bark. She was in seventh grade in 1999, so I know the book is older than that. The book might also be more on the dark side of fantasy.

Comment: We will assume, since you don't specify otherwise, that the book was in English, but it might help if you told us what country she was in when she read it.

Comment: the book was english and the united states is where she read it sorry didnt think about the language or area

Answer (score 4):

I know this is super old,but I was also looking for this book and I think I finally found it! It’s [*The Stranger*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/308858.The_Stranger) by Caroline B. Cooney

> From the first moment she sees him in class, Nicoletta is drawn to Jethro, fascinated by his dark, mysterious face. She is attracted yet repelled, interested but afraid. Nicoletta becomes obsessed, unable to think of anything but this strange boy.
>
> But she knows so little about him.
>
> Until she follows him to a deserted cave on the edge of town ... and learns the truth.
>
> Jethro is not like the others. No, not at all.
>
> He has a terrifying secret. A secret no one must ever find out.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### *[The Frightened Forest](http://www.annturnbull.com/books/frightenedforest.htm)*, by Ann Turnbull

I have not read it myself, but I understand that it is young adult fiction, and that one of the plot elements involves a boy being turned into a tree by an evil witch.

This seems to be the most common cover:

[image: *The Frightened Forest*]